# How to make this regex in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

A few min ago I found out that mysql accepts regex, and is great becouse I think it can solve my problem, but I don't know how to write it. So, I need something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE name REGEXP 'regex code'
```

To give a little more explanation, the name must be in this format: 123425HT and not string99-123425HT. The 123425HT and string99-123425HT  is taken arbitrary

Please Help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE str REGEXP "^([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]{2})$";
```

This regexp will found strings which starting from any digits and two small or big characters, for example:

- 123123hd
- 12345435MF
- 6572Sg

If you want use only 6 digits change from `[0-9]+` to `[0-9]{6}`

Comment: Also of note, if the questioner wants fixed length 6 digit prefix, the `+` can be replaced with `{6}`